# In Awk, are $_ and $0 synonyms?

Tags: awk

I find no reference to `$_` in the Gnu Awk manual or the Wikipedia page, but I used it by mistake from a Perl habit and it seems to be identical to `$0`.

```
ping www.bbc.co.uk | awk '{print NR,$_}'
ping www.bbc.co.uk | awk '{print NR,$0}'
```

Is it some very old deprecated behaviour nobody's bothered to remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would get the same behaviour by using `$any_undefined_variable` instead of `$_`. The underscore is a valid variable name, and since the variable is undefined, its value in a numeric context defaults to zero, i.e., it is indeed equivalent to `$0` but not because of `$_` being a special case (which it isn't).

Comment: You can define the value for `_`, e.g., `echo foo bar | gawk -v _=2 '{ print $_ }'` prints `bar`. So I wouldn't recommend making a habit of assuming `_` to equal zero.

Answer (score 2):

In OP's code:

```
ping www.bbc.co.uk | awk '{print NR,$_}'
```

***Explanation:*** Above `awk` code its considering `_` as a variable here, since no value is defined for variable `_` so its value is zero(`0`) that's why it becomes from `NR,$_` to `NR,$0` and hence printing current line. So there is no special meaning for `$_` unlike perl etc.

So even someone tries like: `ping www.bbc.co.uk | awk '{print NR,$E}'` also will print the samething.